# json_modify on condition

Tags: sql-server, json, sql-server-2019, xml, json-path

As in my [previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/304001/enumerating-json-arrays-with-openjson), I am working on migrating my XML based procedures to JSON ones. My newest struggle is with json_modify

I'm used to using .modify with XPATH to be able to modify XMLs on the fly.

For example, if I have an XML like the following (example taken from SqlShack)

```
<users>
  <user user_id="1">
    <fname>Josef</fname>
    <lname>Brown</lname>
    <email_>jo0@adventure-works.com</email_>
    <gender>M</gender>
  </user>
  <user user_id="2">
    <fname>Katie</fname>
    <lname>McAskill-White</lname>
    <email_>katie0@adventure-works.com</email_>
  </user>
  <user user_id="2">
    <fname>Maddie</fname>
    <lname>Brown</lname>
    <email_>madhatter@adventure-works.com</email_>
  </user>
</users>
```

And I wanted to change the names of all users with user_id="2" to "Nat", I could write the following:

```
xml.modify('replace value of (/users/user[@user_id=("2")]/fname/text()) with "Nat"')
```

Now let's talk about JSON. Suppose I had the following JSON

```
{"Users":
  [{"user_id":1,"fname":"Josef","lname":"Brown","email":"jo0@adventure-works.com","gender":"M"},
   {"user_id":2,"fname":"Katie","lname":"McAskill-White","email":"katie0@adventure-works.com"},
   {"user_id":2,"fname":"Maddie","lname":"Brown","email":"madhatter@adventure-works.com"}]
}
```

I want to do the same I did above, but with this JSON. How do I use json_modify to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot actually modify multiple nodes at the same time using `.modify` anyway. You would normally do that in a loop or a recursive CTE, or by rebuilding the XML.

It is far more complicated to do this with JSON, as JPath in SQL Server does not support any form of predicate. For every level that needs a predicate, you need to break it out separately.

Let's assume you want to only do it on the first item. You could use `JSON_MODIFY`, but you would need to build the JPath dynamically, which only works on SQL Server 2017+.

```sql
UPDATE t
SET json = JSON_MODIFY(t.json, '$.Users[' + j.[key] + '].fname', 'Nat')
FROM t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 j.[key]
    FROM OPENJSON(t.json, '$.Users') j
    WHERE JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.user_id') = '2'
) j;
```

Or for a variable you can do

```sql
SET @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, '$.Users[' + (
    SELECT TOP 1 j.[key]
    FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.Users') j
    WHERE JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.user_id') = '2'
  ) + '].fname', 'Nat');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1c445798717b77a805bb0a6d93b5af43)

As you can see, it gets complex and only works with one value, and only on SQL Server 2017+.

A better alternative, especially if you have multiple values, is to rebuild the JSON.

You could go the whole hog and rebuild each object:

```sql
UPDATE t
SET json = j.json
FROM t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      user_id,
      fname = CASE WHEN user_id = 2 THEN 'Nat' ELSE fname END,
      lname,
      email,
      gender
    FROM OPENJSON(t.json, '$.Users')
      WITH (
        user_id int,
        fname varchar(50),
        lname varchar(50),
        email varchar(255),
        gender char(1)
      ) j
    FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Users')
) j(json);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9dce23067a5b7c142697fde4978bbd3c)

But the easiest way in a lot of cases is to rebuild only down to the level above the one you need to change, and do the final one with `JSON_MODIFY`.

In this particular case, that means you just need to do an array break-out with `OPENJSON` and no schema, then conditionally `JSON_MODIFY` the objects. SQL Server doesn't have `JSON_AGG`, so we need to hack that with `STRING_AGG`:

```sql
UPDATE t
SET json = j.json
FROM t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT Users = JSON_QUERY('[' + STRING_AGG(CAST(
        CASE WHEN JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.user_id') = '2'
          THEN JSON_MODIFY(j.value, '$.fname', 'Nat')
          ELSE j.value END
      AS nvarchar(max)), ',') + ']')
    FROM OPENJSON(t.json, '$.Users') j
    FOR JSON PATH
) j(json);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3a61f00d991e13e7fa56dfa5017b2525)